# Why does my product not show the full answer when dividing

Tags: c, division

For example, for the first number I'll put 6, which turns into 7 
and for the second number I'll put 4, which turns into 2 
and when it shows what 7 divided by 3 is, it only shows 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int a;  
int b = 1;  
int c;  
int x;  
int y = 2;  
int z;  
float d;  
int main()  
{  
    printf("enter first number\n");  
    scanf("%d", &a);  
    c = a + b;  
    printf("this is your number increased by one\n");  
    printf("%d", c);  
    printf("\n");  
    printf("enter second number\n");  
    scanf("%d", &x);  
    z = x - y;  
    printf("this is your number decreased by two\n");  
    printf("%d", z);  
    printf("\n");  
    printf("This is your first number divided by your second number\n");  
    d = c / z;  
    printf("%f",d);  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `c` and `z` are both `int`s, so `c / z` is an `int`, with the fractional part truncated. This happens before the assignment to the `float` variable `d`.

Comment: Use `(float) c/z`

Comment: Try to ask exact minimal question.  you simply can define 3 varuables a b c and perform division then ask why the result is 2. read [mcve]

Comment: Note that you should avoid global variables — variables defined outside a function — whenever possible.  In this code, all the variables should be inside the function, initialized explicitly (to 0 if there wasn't already an initializer) if you need to initialize the variable before use.  In fact, you don't need any extra initializers; you either read values into the variables, or assign them, or use a previously initialized value.  Strictly, you should check that each of the `scanf()` operations succeeds before using the value that you expect to be returned via the pointer arguments.

Answer (score 2):

According to [§6.5.5/5 of the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p6),

> When integers are divided, the result of the **/** operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.

Since both `c` and `z` are integer types, the fractional part of the result is discarded before the assignment to the `float` variable `d` is made.

To get the desired result, you could multiply one of the operands by `1.0` to force floating point division:

```
d = c / (1.0 * z);
```

Unrelated, but you should always check the return value from calls to `scanf()`. This function returns the number of successful assignments made. The returned value can be used to check whether input is as expected. If the user enters input that is unexpected, the best case is that the values stored in your variables would be surprising; the worst case is that the program has undefined behavior, followed by a nuclear winter....

Comment: Thanking comments are considered as noise. It must be either accept or upvote that counts and helps others filter out good, bad, ugly and accepted answers